# Excel VBA: Generating and deleting TextBoxes on runtime

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, controls, global

I am working on a Userform in which one can add and remove Textboxes. These TextBoxes then can be filled out and by using a CommandButton `SaveData` the content should then safe in the sheet.

In order to do so, I declared a gloabal variable `nFarbe`. Using this variable I am controlling the number of Texboxes. The weird thing is, by initialising the Form calling `LoadTextBox` and `ReadTextBoxContent` the correct number of boxes are loaded and the content is filled in. Howevern, by adding a TextBox `AddColor` the `nFarbe` is increased by 1 in Order to add a TextBox. The additional TextBox shows up, but the content of all boxes but the new one vanishes. This I do not understand since I'm calling `LoadTextBox` and `ReadTextBoxContent` as I do during the initialization. By calling `RemoveColor` `nFarbe`is reduced by 1 in order to delete 1 TextBox. This does not work at all.

Any thouhts? Help is much appreciated!

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
nFarbe = 1
Call LoadTextBox
Call ReadTextBoxContent
    
End Sub

Private Sub AddColor_Click()

nFarbe = nFarbe + 1                 
Call LoadTextBox
Call ReadTextBoxContent

TextBox_nFarbe = nFarbe
    
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveColor_Click()

nFarbe = nFarbe - 1                 
Call LoadTextBox
Call ReadTextBoxContent

TextBox_nFarbe = nFarbe

End Sub

Private Sub SaveData_Click()

    Dim z As Double
    z = 0
    For i = 1 To nFarbe
        z = 31 + i
        Cells(z, 1).Value = Me("ProductColor" & i).Text
    Next i
    
End Sub


Sub LoadTextBox()

Dim NewColorTextbox As Variant
Dim tp As Double                
tp = 25                         
    
    For i = 1 To nFarbe
        
    Set NewColorTextbox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "MyTextBox", True)
        With NewColorTextbox
            .Name = "ProductColor" & i
            .Width = 150
            .Height = 18
            .Top = tp
            .Left = 30
            .ZOrder (0)
            .Font.Size = 10
        End With
    tp = tp + 25
    Next i

End Sub

Sub ReadTextBoxContent()

Dim z As Double
    For i = 1 To nFarbe
    z = 31 + i
    Me("ProductColor" & i) = Cells(z, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The text is not disappearing.  You are adding new Textboxes overtop of the old ones.